# How do I send a base64 string to a Django template

Tags: python, html, django, amazon-s3, base64

My python code gets a file from an aws s3 bucket like so then is rendered in an django html template following normal conventions:

```
    context_dict = {}
    conn = S3Connection(djangoSettings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, djangoSettings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    b = conn.get_bucket(djangoSettings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME) 
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = 'Myfile.png'


    your_bytes = k.get_contents_as_string(headers={'Range' : 'bytes=0-100000'},encoding="base64")

    print your_bytes

    context_dict['bytes'] = your_bytes
    context_dict['otherdata'] = "otherdata"
    return render(request, 'webapp/index.html', context_dict)
```

When I `print your_bytes` it prints the bytes in the terminal displaying my Django server data. but when I try to access the bytes in my Django template like so nothing occurs:

```
<html><body>
   {{ otherdata }}
   {{ bytes }}
</body></html>
```

`bytes` prints nothing but `otherdata` is rendered fine.

In summary how do i send a base 64 string to my django template without conflict?
Or is this a foolish way to send a file to the client?
If so what is the most appropriate way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the value of `print your_bytes`?

Comment: @ElwinArens a large base64 string

Comment: And what does it print if you do `print(type(your_bytes))`?

Comment: Show us how you're rendering the template.  (This seems like a _really critical_ piece of information to leave out of your question...)

Comment: Can you show the rest of the function? including the rendering bit.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes i will

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to escape the content of "bytes"?

```
<html><body>
   {{ otherdata }}
   {{ bytes|force_escape }}
</body></html>
```

Normally if I need to return the file to the client I would either redirect the url of the file or just simply return the json with the url inside.

```
// write file to /media/s3/my-file.jpg
// option1 - redirect
return redirect('/media/s3/my-file.jpg')

// or

// option2 
response_data = {
  'fileUrl': '/media/s3/my-file.jpg',
}

// Pre-Django 1.7 
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
// For Django 1.7+
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse(response_data)
```